# Как сделать поля логина и пароля автозаполняемыми?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть форма, но при добавлении ей атрибута autocomplete="on" автозаполнения при повторном посещении страницы не происходит. Подскажите, что не так

```
<form id="login-form" autocomplete="on">
    <div id="greetings">Добро пожаловать!<p>Для авторизации введите логин и пароль.</p></div>
    <div class="input-label">
        <input id="login" placeholder="Логин" name="log"/>
        <div class="input-val-remove"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-label">
        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Пароль" name="pswrd"/>
        <div class="input-val-remove"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="confirm-login-btn">Войти в систему</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, autocomplete добавляется полям формы, а не самой форме.

Во-вторых, в настройках браузера можно принудительно отключить автозаполнение, так что всё равно работать не будет.

Подробнее: http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/autocomplete

Comment: Соглашусь с @humster_spb. Но как костыль - хранить и подставлять логин из куки, а пароль ... ну увеличивать время жизни сессии.

Comment: Пробовал добавлять и полям, не работает

Comment: Значит, Вы не вполне точно описали задачу. Вы ходите, чтобы при возвращении на страницу в полях уже были подставлены какие-то значения? Тогда autocomplete тут вообще не при чём - он всего лишь помогает заполнять поля. Вам нужно где-то хранить эти данные и каждый раз подставлять в поля. Можно на сервере в базе данных (самое безопасное), можно, как предложил @Nsk, в куках, можно в localStorage